# C# WebRequest. Сформировать HTTP заголовок запроса

Tags: c#, .net

Доброго времени суток!
Необходимо отправлять расписание,в формате XML на сервер в теле POST запроса.

Существует уже написанный клиент с таким функционалом и у меня есть сниффер этого hTTP соединения, снятый программой "HttpAnalyzer":

```
    Отправлено:

POST /upload.php?terminalid=61 HTTP/1.0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------051117113546829
Host: 10.255.247.2
Accept: text/html, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)
Cookie: PHPSESSID=s1cednccmhs6uhvst27hhlup76
Content-Length: 88158

----------051117113546829
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="C:\trunk\export.xml"
Content-Type: 

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tlist>
------------ XML файл
------------



Получено:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Date: Thu, 11 May 2017 08:35:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.19
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 4

true
```

Меня интересует правильно ли я настраиваю WebRequest, ориентируясь на секцию "Отправлено"?

```
 objHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
 var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlRequest.ToString());
 objHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
 objHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
 objHttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true; 

 objHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------051117113546829"
 objHttpWebRequest.Accept = "text/html, */*";
 objHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)";
 objHttpWebRequest.Host= "10.255.247.2";
```

В ответ на такой запрос у меня приходит HttpStatusCode.OK
 и при считывании самого ответа строка "False".
 Файл XML верный, больше нигде косяков быть не должно.

Подозрения у меня на заголовок HTTP.

Попробовал использовать HttpClient.

```
   public async Task<string> SendMultipartHttp(string uri)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html, */*");

                    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent(Boundary))
                    {
                        content.Add(new StreamContent(GenerateStreamFromString(XmlStr)), "username", @"C:\trunk\export.xml");
                        using (var respone = await client.PostAsync(uri, content))
                        {
                            var input = await respone.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                            rtb_log.Text += "Message=  " + respone + "\n";
                            rtb_log.Text += "input=  " + input + "\n";

                            return input;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                Status = $"WebException Исключение: {we.Message}.   Внутренне исключение: {we.InnerException?.Message ?? "" }";
                rtb_log.Text += Status + "\n";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Status = $"Неизвестное Исключение: {ex.Message}.   Внутренне исключение: {ex.InnerException?.Message ?? "" }";
                rtb_log.Text += Status + "\n";
            }

            return null;
        }
```

сам XML файл отправляется по правилам multipart используя boundary.

```
    ----------051117113546829
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="C:\trunk\export.xml"
    Content-Type: 

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <tlist>
     XML файл
    </tlist>
----------051117113546829--
```

Я вставляю свой XML в такой шаблон и отправляю через SendMultipartHttp.
В ответ получаю false.

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` - вот это вызывает сомнения. В дотнете строки представлены в формате UTF-16. Если хоть один символ не попадает в диапазон ASCII, то получится мусор. Используйте `Encoding.Unicode`.

Comment: Ок, сейчас попробую

Comment: Важно ли заполнять все секции в заголовке HTTP, или это зависит от конкретной настройке сервера?

Comment: нет не помогла кодировка.

Comment: еще я попробовал objHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'". Тоже не помогло

Comment: Вопрос все еще актуален. Если исходить снятого лога, то правильно ли я формирую заголовок запроса? Или это не так важно и стоит искать ошибки в другом?

Answer (score 1):

Протестировали клиента с коллегой который написал сервер на PHP

код сервера:

```
    $data = [];
if ($_FILES['username']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK          
    && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['username']['tmp_name'])) {
    $file = file_get_contents($_FILES['username']['tmp_name']);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($file);
    foreach ($xml as $k => $v)
        $data = $v;
}
```

Код клиента с использованием HttpClient:

```
public async Task<string> SendMultipartHttp(string uri, string date, string boundary)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html, */*");
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "10.255.247.2");


            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary))
            {
                content.Add(new StreamContent(GenerateStreamFromString(date)), "\"username\"", "\"xDoc.xml\"");
                using (var respone = await client.PostAsync(uri, content))
                {
                    var input = await respone.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    rtb_log.Text += "Message=  " + respone + "\n";
                    rtb_log.Text += "input=  " + input + "\n";

                    return input;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        Status = $"WebException Исключение: {we.Message}.   Внутренне исключение: {we.InnerException?.Message ?? "" }";
        rtb_log.Text += Status + "\n";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Status = $"Неизвестное Исключение: {ex.Message}.   Внутренне исключение: {ex.InnerException?.Message ?? "" }";
        rtb_log.Text += Status + "\n";
    }
    return null;
}
```

Использование

```
//XDoc - дерево Xml файла
//отправка........
var boundary = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var xmlVersion = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
var resultXmlDoc = xmlVersion + XDoc.ToString();

await SendMultipartHttp(uri, resultXmlDoc, boundary);
```

В такой паре все работает!!
Почему не принимает нужный мне сервер Xml я не выяснил...

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я знаю, по дефолту общение между браузером и сервером должно быть в UTF-8 кодировке.

`objHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'"` - Этот заголовок используйте, по идее правильный должен быть.

А где передача байт в запрос? Наподобие:

```
using (var sw = objHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    sw.Write(this.Encoding.GetBytes(bytes), 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

`objHttpWebRequest.Accept = "text/html, */*";` - Это не обязательно, этот хедер указывает какие типы может понять клиент.

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
var objHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlRequest.ToString());
objHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
objHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
objHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8";
using (var sw = objHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    sw.Write(this.Encoding.GetBytes(bytes), 0, bytes.Length);
}
var request = objHttpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Напишите, что отвечает сервер.

Comment: Узнал, что передача должна быть в multipart/form-data. также указывается boundary для разделения запросов.

Comment: добавил изменения в главный вопрос, добавил функцию SendMultipartHttp().

Comment: @Aldmi, Вы уверены, что сервер работает корректно и что нет ошибок в xml файле? Я не вижу проблем с заголовками.

Comment: Да уде все варианты перепробовал и с помощью HttpClient, используя multypart. И WebRequest создавая multypart тело в ручную с помощью boundary. Формат multypart выдержал как точ в точ. Сейчас мой коллега пишет на PHP сервер и  мы будем тестировать с ним. Всем спасибо за участие.

Comment: @Aldmi, не пропадай, как разберёшься в ошибке ответь на свой же вопрос, мне интересно в чём же проблема.